# Duplicate existing table with existing dax formulas

Tags: powerbi, dax

I have an existing table with plenty of dax formulas set up.

Every month I would like to add in another excel source of the new month's info (the base file will be the same as the existing table above) [e.g. same rows, data fields and columns). Is there anyway i can duplicate my original table with the dax formulas and then replace the duplicated table with a new source every month?

The goal is to track the variances every month. Ideally, it should be a snap shot of jan,feb,march, etc.. however the dax formulas can't be copied over. Is there any workaround?

Thanks in advance

I tried to duplicate table in power query but the dax formulas will not be captured.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of replacing the data source each month, you can append the new month data to your existing table in Power Query. This way, your DAX formulas will remain intact, and you can use them to analyze the combined dataset.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-query/append-queries

Or you can parameterize your data source in Power Query.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/connect-data/desktop-dynamic-m-query-parameters

For Power BI Premium or SQL Server Analysis Services 2019+, you can use Calculation Groups in Tabular Editor to apply the same calculations (like in your case time intelligence calculations) across multiple measures without having to rewrite DAX formulas for each measure.

https://www.sqlbi.com/calculation-groups/